# I want to create ruby on rails website on multi-language

Tags: ruby, internationalization, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rails-i18n

I'm using ruby on rails 3.2 with psql. Currently my website is in english language. Now I want to create it in multiple language. My website is a kind of CMS. All pages and link of pages are in the table. So I'm confused how to convert data from english to french or german language. I'll not use any yml files.

Help me :(

Answer (score 0):

You should look at the [globalize2](https://github.com/joshmh/globalize2) plugin. You should be able to translate your records.